# my mysql SELECT case can't return 3 columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return 3 columns with the query below. the current query works fine.

```
SELECT cat, COUNT(*) as count FROM
                        (SELECT case WHEN `cat_type` = 'PREMIUM' then '1'
                                     WHEN `cat_type` = 'NOT PREMIUM' then '2'
                                     WHEN `cat_type` = 'GOLD' then '3'
                                     WHEN `cat_type` = 'EXECUTIVE' then '4'
                                     WHEN `cat_type` = 'NOT PROVIDED' then '-1'
                                     else '-2'
                                end AS cat FROM `ab` AS s
                                 JOIN `make` AS m
                                 WHERE s.make_code = m.make_code 
                              ) AS someRandomAliasHere
                                    GROUP BY cat
                                    ORDER BY CAST(cat AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

when i try and return another column `cat_type` i get an error

```
SELECT cat, cat_type, COUNT(*) as count FROM ....
```

The error i get is

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'cat_type' in 'field list'
```

but `cat_type` does exist in my `ab` table. any idea what i'm missing? Thanks

Comment: so i add `someRandomAliasHere.cat_type` after COUNT(*) ?

Comment: Perhaps its because of Join.

cat might be in both table but not the cat_type

Comment: Your use of `CASE WHEN` is wrong, check the docs!

Comment: You are mixing up the two syntaxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `cat_type` in the subquery.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT cat, cat_type, COUNT(*) as count
FROM (SELECT (case WHEN `cat_type` = 'PREMIUM' then 1
                   WHEN `cat_type` = 'NOT PREMIUM' then 2
                   WHEN `cat_type` = 'GOLD' then 3
                   WHEN `cat_type` = 'EXECUTIVE' then 4
                   WHEN `cat_type` = 'NOT PROVIDED' then -1
                   else -2
              end) AS cat, *
      FROM `ab` AS s JOIN
           `make` AS m
            USING (make_code)
    ) AS someRandomAliasHere
GROUP BY cat, cat_type
ORDER BY abs(cat) asc
```

Note the following:

1. Added `*` to the subquery to capture all the columns.
2. Changed the `join` syntax.  Not only are explicit joins better but the `using` clause allows the use of `*` without having to worry about duplicate names among the joined column.
3. Removed the single quotes from the constant values for `cat`.  You are treating these as numbers in the `order by`, so use numbers for the values.
4. Changed the order by to `abs()` rather than casting to `unsigned`.  However, do you really want unsigned here?

Comment: i had to replace the * with `end) AS cat, fuel_type` only then did it work tho. i also used `CAST(cat AS UNSIGNED)` to sort it by cat_type. (1,2,3,4,-1)

Answer (score 2):

Your `cat_type` exists in `ab` table.

But your `ab` table does not exists in your main select.
It only exists within the sub query which returns `someRandomAliasHere` to you.
So you should likely select `cat_type` from the same select as you select your cases.
Then you should have access to it, but it would then likely mess with your group by / count.

You'll properly need a more advanced query for what you're after.

Comment: It could be the reason

Answer (score 1):

You're not selecting `cat_type` into `someRandomAliasHere`, hence it's not available to your main select. This should fix it:

```
SELECT cat, cat_type, COUNT(*) as count FROM
    (SELECT case WHEN `cat_type` = 'PREMIUM' then '1'
                 WHEN `cat_type` = 'NOT PREMIUM' then '2'
                 WHEN `cat_type` = 'GOLD' then '3'
                 WHEN `cat_type` = 'EXECUTIVE' then '4'
                 WHEN `cat_type` = 'NOT PROVIDED' then '-1'
                 else '-2'
        end AS cat, cat_type FROM `ab` AS s
         JOIN `make` AS m
         WHERE s.make_code = m.make_code 
      ) AS someRandomAliasHere
GROUP BY cat, cat_type
ORDER BY CAST(cat AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You needed to include the column in subquery first and then reference that using the table.col

Try below

```
SELECT someRandomAliasHere.cat_type, cat, COUNT(*) as count FROM
                            (SELECT cat_type, case WHEN `cat_type` = 'PREMIUM' then '1'
                                         WHEN `cat_type` = 'NOT PREMIUM' then '2'
                                         WHEN `cat_type` = 'GOLD' then '3'
                                         WHEN `cat_type` = 'EXECUTIVE' then '4'
                                         WHEN `cat_type` = 'NOT PROVIDED' then '-1'
                                         else '-2'
                                    end AS cat FROM `ab` AS s
                                     JOIN `make` AS m
                                     WHERE s.make_code = m.make_code 
                                  ) AS someRandomAliasHere
                                        GROUP BY cat
                                        ORDER BY CAST(cat AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also select the column cat_type, so that someRandomAliasHere owns the column.

```
SELECT cat, cat_type, COUNT(*) as count FROM
                            (SELECT case WHEN `cat_type` = 'PREMIUM' then '1'
                                         WHEN `cat_type` = 'NOT PREMIUM' then '2'
                                         WHEN `cat_type` = 'GOLD' then '3'
                                         WHEN `cat_type` = 'EXECUTIVE' then '4'
                                         WHEN `cat_type` = 'NOT PROVIDED' then '-1'
                                         else '-2'
                                end AS cat, cat_type FROM `ab` AS s
                                 JOIN `make` AS m
                                 WHERE s.make_code = m.make_code 
                              ) AS someRandomAliasHere
                                    GROUP BY cat, cat_type
                                    ORDER BY CAST(cat AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

Dont forget to add cat_type in GROUP BY too.